# 3d maps aren't showing up on iPhone 5 when zooming in

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, apple-maps

My team and I are working on an iPhone app that uses Apple Mapkit. We are using Xcode 5 as the IDE. A few weeks ago, when we were testing it, the 3d buildings view displayed if the user zoomed in close enough on the map. However, when we try to test it now, the map display stays two-dimensional no matter how much we zoom in.

Is there some 3d map setting we could have accidentally turned off?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out `mapView.showsBuildings`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. You're answer led me in the right direction for this. Thanks again.